# How to store UserID username in Titanium

Tags: titanium

My app is similar to facebook. 
I want to retain the userID/Username upon login screen, so that i could use it at rest of the application for queries online data.

I tried storing it in a javascript object after successful login, but it gets washed away when i move to other screens.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `App.Properties` API.

Example, right from the [docs](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module).

`Titanium.App.Properties.setString("my_prop","cool");`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Ti.Facebook.loggedIn) {
    if(Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('fbid')) {
        var fbid = Ti.App.Properties.getString('fbid');
    }
}
```

You can use the `hasProperty` to verify they have logged in in the past and when they do logout you can use the `removeProperty` so that your app assumes they haven't logged in and starts over.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to store the information in the properties, you should be aware that the is information persisted on the device.

The use of properties for short term storage IMHO should be avoided if possible.

You have two choices, one store your variables in the Titanium namespace

```
Titanium.App.credentials = { "user" :"username", "pwd":"password123"};
```

Or create your own namespace and store your variable there. This will ensure you values are available throughout the application, but not stored on the device.

There is an example on my blog here http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/6519148138/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-global-variables-scopes

Comment: That's what i have done eventually. Actually, i was referencing wrong object while retrieving, so i was getting wrong value. Thanks anyways.