# Titanium cloud.users.show

Tags: ios, titanium

In my titanium app.js, i have the cloud register/login code snippets below...

register:

```
var btnR = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title: 'register',
top: 350,
left: 10,
width: 100,
height:28
});

    btnR.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Cloud.Users.create ({
                username: username.value,
                password: password.value,
                password_confirmation : passwordConfirmation.value,
                firstName: firstName.value,
                lastName: lastName.value,
                email : email.value
    }, function (e) {
           if (e.success) {
            var user = e.users[0];
        Ti.App.fireEvent('register');
        } else {
            alert('fail :' + e.message);
        }
      });
    });
```

login:

```
var btnL = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title: 'log in',
top: 190,
left: 10,
width: 100,
height:50
});

btnL.addEventListener('click', function(){
Cloud.Users.login({
    login: userNameField.value,
    password: passwordField.value,
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var user = e.users[0];
            Ti.App.fireEvent('login');
    } else {
        alert('fail:' + e.message);
    }
    });
});
```

And in my home.js, i have the following code.

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
    hintText: 'search here',
    showCancel:true,
    height:35,
    top:10,
    center:0,
    width:250
});
view6.add(search);


search.addEventListener('cancel', function(e)
{
Titanium.API.info('search bar cancel fired');
search.blur();
});
```

Okay, my question is, if i want a user to be able to search for other users through the search bar, how am i going to do it. I tried the code below but it gives me an error.."can't find variable userId at home.js". Thanks as you help me.

```
search.addEventListener('return', function(e)
{
Cloud.Users.show({
    user_id: userId
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var user = e.users[0];
        alert('Success:\n' +
            'id: ' + user.id + '\n' +
            'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\n' +
            'last name: ' + user.last_name);
} else {
        alert('Oops:' + e.message);
   }
    });
});
```

Comment: plus..the above code is a seperate url file not the the main window.

Comment: So where does the value for userId come from? From what I can see here, it is undefined when you send it...

Answer (score 1):

if you use your code from the login question you asked here

[Titanium Login/Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300984/titanium-login-registration)

And us the user_id from

```
Cloud.Users.login({
  login: userNameField.value,
  password: passwordField.value,
}, function (e) {
  if (e.success) {
    var user = e.users[0];
    user_id = user.id; // assign user id

    showUser(user_id);

    alert('success');
  } else {
    alert('Unable to log you in:' + e.message);
  }
});
```

create a function to show the user

```
function showUser(_userId) {
    Cloud.Users.show({
      user_id: _userId
    }, function (e) {
      if (e.success) {
        var user = e.users[0];
        alert('Success:\n' +
            'id: ' + user.id + '\n' +
            'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\n' +
            'last name: ' + user.last_name);
      } else {
        alert('Oops:' + e.message);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Aaron, firstly, i am a fan/follower of your blog. I just tried your code but it din't work for me, maybe i dint do it well. Permit me, i am still relatively new to mobil dev. ***I am trying to login a user into the homepage which is working fine but i would like the user to be able to search for other users of the app through the 'search bar'.

Comment: you are going to need to provide more code if you want additional assistance

Comment: i have edited my previous code with more code. Thanks as you help me.